# Add image to a list item in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

I have a simple shopping list and need to be able to upload an image to individual list items. Using MongoDB and AngularJS.

The image should be bound to the $scope.list.items therefore adding an image to a list item (eg. a picture of bread). How can I upload an image and bind it as part of that object? Basically the list of items would also contain images once this is complete.

HTML for displaying items:

```
<ul class="list-group">
            <li style="color:{{list.color}}" class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in list.items | orderBy:propertyName:reverse | filter: search ">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isChecked" ng-click="editItem()">
                {{item.name}} - {{item.priority}}
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="removeItem(item)"></i>&nbsp

                <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true" href ng-click="showEdit = !showEdit" ng-show="!showEdit"></i><br>
                <small class="form-text text-muted">Note: {{item.note}}</small>
                <div ng-show = "showEdit"> 
                    <h4>Edit {{item.name}}</h4>
                    <form ng-submit="editItem()">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" ng-model="item.name" maxlength="25" required>
                        <select class="form-control" name="priority" id="priority" ng-model="item.priority" required>
                            <option value="">Priority</option>
                            <option value="High">High</option>
                            <option value="Low">Low</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="note" id="note" ng-model="item.note" maxlength="255" value= " ">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" ng-click="showEdit = !showEdit">Update</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <br>

            </li> 
        </ul>
```

Here is the HTML for adding an item:

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-custom" href ng-click="showAddItem = !showAddItem" ng-show="!showAddItem">Add Item</button>
        <div ng-show="showAddItem" class="add-item">
            <h4>Add Item</h4>
            <form ng-submit="addItem()">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" ng-model="newItem.name" placeholder="Item" maxlength="25" required>
                <select class="form-control" name="priority" id="priority" ng-model="newItem.priority" required>
                    <option value="">Priority</option>
                    <option value="High">High</option>
                    <option value="Low">Low</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="note" id="note" ng-model="newItem.note" placeholder="Note" maxlength="255" value= " ">

                <button class="btn btn-default btn-add" type="submit">Add</button>&nbsp<span class="close-box" ng-click="showAddItem = !showAddItem"><u>close</u></span>    
            </form>
             <!-- <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-custom" href="">Add Item</button> -->
        </div><br><br>
        <a ng-href="#/home"><button class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-home">Save & Return</button></a>

    </div>
```

And the controller for adding an item:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.controller('ShoppingListController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', 'API_BASE', '$location', function($scope, $http, $routeParams, API_BASE, $location){


    // GET SPECIFIC LIST
    $scope.list = [];
    var id = $routeParams.id;

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: API_BASE + 'shopping-lists/' + id
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.list = response.data[0];
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log('it did not work');
        console.log(response.statusText);
    });


    // REMOVE LIST
    $scope.removeList = function(){
        var id = $scope.list.id;
        console.log(id);
        $http.delete(API_BASE + 'shopping-lists/' + id)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('you deleted :' + $scope.list);
            })
            .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
            });
        $location.path('/home');    
    };

    // RANDOM ID
    function makeid()
    {
        var text = "";
        var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

        for( var i=0; i < 20; i++ ){
            text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
        }

        text += Date.now();

        return text;
    }


    // ADD ITEM
    $scope.addItem = function(){
        var created = new Date();
        var newID = makeid();

        if($scope.list.hasOwnProperty('items') === false){
            $scope.list.items = [];
        }
        $scope.list.items.push({
            name : $scope.newItem.name,
            priority : $scope.newItem.priority,
            note: $scope.newItem.note,
            isChecked: false,
            listId: $scope.list.id,
            created: created,
            id: newID
        });
        // console.log($scope.list.items);
        $http.put(API_BASE + 'shopping-lists/', $scope.list)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            })
            .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
            });

        // Reset input fields after submit
        $scope.newItem = {
            name: "",
            priority: "",
            note: ""
        };
```

Comment: what do you mean? Do you want to add an image url or upload an image from the browser?

Comment: Upload an image

Comment: where is `list` used - should there be an HTML element bound to it?

Comment: Updated with list items displayed

Comment: Need to be far more specific about what it is you are trying to do and what problems you are encountering. Documentation of what? take a few minutes to read [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code to add an image to the list, and then altered the list item display to check for properties:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isChecked" ng-click="editItem()" ng-show="item.hasOwnProperty('isChecked')">
<img ng-show="item.hasOwnProperty('imageSrc')" src="{{ item.imageSrc }}" />
```

And I made a simple function to add an image item that has an `imageSrc` property, used in the image that only appears if that property is set.

```
$scope.list.items.push({
        imageSrc: 'http://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-QErodXkgwBc/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAWQ/LPUidgUqYHs/photo.jpg?sz=32',
        priority: '',
        note: 'Evan',
        //don't include this property - which will make the ng-show for the checkbox false
        //isChecked: true,
        created: new Date(),
        id: -1
      });
```

. This is one way to do it but you could do it differently.

### Sample

```js
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.constant('API_BASE','/api');
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {}]);
app.controller('ShoppingListController', ['$scope','$http', '$routeParams', 'API_BASE', '$location', function($scope, $http, $routeParams, API_BASE, $location){

    // GET SPECIFIC LIST
    $scope.list = {items: []};
    $scope.showAddItem = true;
    var id = $routeParams.id;
  //commenting this out because we don't have access to your server
    /*$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: API_BASE + 'shopping-lists/' + id
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.list = response.data[0];
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log('it did not work');
        console.log(response.statusText);
    });*/


    // REMOVE LIST
    $scope.removeList = function(){
        var id = $scope.list.id;
        console.log(id);
        $http.delete(API_BASE + 'shopping-lists/' + id)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('you deleted :' + $scope.list);
            })
            .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
            });
        $location.path('/home');    
    };

    // RANDOM ID
    function makeid()     {
        var text = "";
        var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        for( var i=0; i < 20; i++ ){
            text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
        }
        text += Date.now();
        return text;
    }


    // ADD ITEM
    $scope.addItem = function(){
        var created = new Date();
        var newID = makeid();

        if($scope.list.hasOwnProperty('items') === false){
            $scope.list.items = [];
        }
        $scope.list.items.push({
            name : $scope.newItem.name,
            priority : $scope.newItem.priority,
            note: $scope.newItem.note,
            isChecked: false,
            listId: $scope.list.id,
            created: created,
            id: newID
        });
        // console.log($scope.list.items);
        $http.put(API_BASE + 'shopping-lists/', $scope.list)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            })
            .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
            });

        // Reset input fields after submit
        $scope.newItem = {
            name: "",
            priority: "",
            note: ""
        }; 
    };
    $scope.addImage = function(){
      if($scope.list.hasOwnProperty('items') === false){
            $scope.list.items = [];
        }
      $scope.list.items.push({
        imageSrc: 'http://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-QErodXkgwBc/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAWQ/LPUidgUqYHs/photo.jpg?sz=32',
        priority: '',
        note: 'Evan',
        //don't include this property - which will make the ng-show for the checkbox false
        //isChecked: true,
        created: new Date(),
        id: -1
      });
    };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ShoppingListController">
  
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-custom" href ng-click="showAddItem = !showAddItem" ng-show="!showAddItem">Add Item</button>
  <div style="font-style: italic">//code for adding item
 
  <ul class="list-group">
            <li style="color:{{ list.color }}" class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in list.items | orderBy:propertyName:reverse | filter: search ">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isChecked" ng-click="editItem()" ng-show="item.hasOwnProperty('isChecked')">
                <img ng-show="item.hasOwnProperty('imageSrc')" src="{{ item.imageSrc }}" />
                {{item.name}} - {{ item.priority }}
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="removeItem(item)"></i>&nbsp;

                <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true" href ng-click="showEdit = !showEdit" ng-show="!showEdit"></i><br>
                <small class="form-text text-muted">Note: {{ item.note }}</small>
                <div ng-show = "showEdit"> 
                    <h4>Edit {{ item.name }}</h4>
                    <form ng-submit="editItem()">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" ng-model="item.name" maxlength="25" required>
                        <select class="form-control" name="priority" id="priority" ng-model="item.priority" required>
                            <option value="">Priority</option>
                            <option value="High">High</option>
                            <option value="Low">Low</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="note" id="note" ng-model="item.note" maxlength="255" value= " ">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" ng-click="showEdit = !showEdit">Update</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <br>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <button ng-click="addImage()" >Add image</button></div>
```

Comment: This worked, but the second addImage function was unnecessary. Thanks for the help.

Comment: alright cool - the `addImage` function was just for demonstration purposes - did you see more than one?

Comment: If you feel this answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.